# Vanillla Javascript show hide content using data-type

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, but hopefully, it is. I have different sections that can be edited on a checkout process. So if the client clicks the edit button for the relevant section it should hide the info section then show the edit section. my thinking was to use data type because of trying to keep the javascript as dry as possible? so this is what I have but not to sure how to approach it.

the idea is on click to get the data-type of the clicked edit button and match it to the id of the section to be shown then add a class of show to it. I got it working but initially, I have to do a double click to fire it off and if I do a console log the "clicked" count climbs exponentially.

also, feels that having two functions is repetitive..?

```js
function editDetails() {

  let trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-link');

  trigger.forEach(function(click) {
    click.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      const target = this.getAttribute('data-checkout');
      const checkoutSection = document.getElementById('checkout-' + target);
      const checkoutEditSection = document.getElementById('edit-checkout-' + target);

      if (checkoutEditSection.classList) {
        checkoutEditSection.classList.add('show');
      }
      if (checkoutSection.classList) {
        checkoutSection.classList.add('hide');
      }

      e.preventDefault();
    })


  });
}

function cancelDetails() {

  let trigger = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-cancel');

  trigger.forEach(function(click) {
    click.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      const target = this.getAttribute('data-checkout');
      const checkoutSection = document.getElementById('checkout-' + target);
      const checkoutEditSection = document.getElementById('edit-checkout-' + target);

      if (checkoutEditSection.classList) {
        checkoutEditSection.classList.remove('show');
      }
      if (checkoutSection.classList) {
        checkoutSection.classList.remove('hide');
      }

      console.log(target);
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  });
}
```

```css
.edit-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.info {
  padding: 4em;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.details {
  padding: 4em;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--lg">

  <a onclick="editDetails()" data-checkout="personal" class="edit-link">Edit Personal Details</a>
  <a onclick="editDetails()" data-checkout="payment" class="edit-link">Edit Payment Details</a>

  <div id="checkout-personal" class="contact-info info">this is the Personal Details content</div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-personal" class="contact-info details">
    this is the Personal Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="personal" onclick="cancelDetails()">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn" onclick="saveDetails()">Save</a>

  </div>
  <div id="checkout-payment" class="payment-info info">this is the Payment Details content</div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-payment" class="payment-info details">this is the Payment Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="payment" onclick="cancelDetails()">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn" onclick="saveDetails()">Save</a></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I clicked edit and `[<>]` for you

Comment: Don't ADD eventlisteners in a button that can be clicked more than once!!! - Loog up `delegate`

Comment: don;t think i follow @mplungjan

Comment: Every time I click editDetails, you add a function to the click of all `'.edit-link'` - you need only to add that once and add it to the static container, then any click on the container will reveal the target in e.target

Comment: A snippet of your code was produced is what is meant by the edit comment

Comment: @mplungjan so how would i change my code to do this?

Comment: @mplungjan so do you mean i should not run it in a forEach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Every time we click editDetails, you add a function to the click of all '.edit-link' - you need only to add that once and add it to the static container, then any click on the container will reveal the target in e.target

Delegate like this

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("edit-link") || tgt.classList.contains("btn-cancel")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const cancel = tgt.classList.contains("btn-cancel");
    const target = tgt.getAttribute('data-checkout');
    const checkoutSection = document.getElementById('checkout-' + target);
    const checkoutEditSection = document.getElementById('edit-checkout-' + target);

    checkoutEditSection.classList.toggle('show', !cancel);
    checkoutSection.classList.toggle('hide', cancel);
  }
})
```

```css
.edit-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.info {
  padding: 4em;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.details {
  padding: 4em;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--lg">

  <a data-checkout="personal" class="edit-link">Edit Personal Details</a>
  <a data-checkout="payment" class="edit-link">Edit Payment Details</a>

  <div id="checkout-personal" class="contact-info info">
    this is the Personal Details content
  </div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-personal" class="contact-info details">
    this is the Personal Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="personal">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn" onclick="saveDetails()">Save</a>
  </div>
  <div id="checkout-payment" class="payment-info info">
    this is the Payment Details content
  </div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-payment" class="payment-info details">
    this is the Payment Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="payment">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn" onclick="saveDetails()">Save</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is something wrong with the code because the cancel is closing both the details and the edit section

Comment: Ok, you get the idea. I'll let you figure that one out

Comment: I suggest you have only .hide and not .show and just toggle that class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure all your requirements but here I show how to add event handlers for each button and call a function to simply toggle the `hide` class.

Your other work for the buttons can be placed in the functions as appropriate;

```js
function showAction(text) {
  const showMe = document.getElementById('showme');
  showMe.textContent = text;
}

function clickEventhandler(event) {
  showAction('Clicked:' + this.textContent)
  const target = this.getAttribute('data-checkout');
  const checkoutSection = document.getElementById('checkout-' + target);
  const checkoutEditSection = document.getElementById('edit-checkout-' + target);
  checkoutSection.classList.toggle('hide');
  checkoutEditSection.classList.toggle('hide');
  event.preventDefault();
}

function saveEventHandler(event) {
  showAction('Clicked:' + this.textContent);
  clickEventhandler.call(this, event);
}

function cancelEventHandler(event) {
  showAction('Clicked:' + this.textContent);
  clickEventhandler.call(this, event);
}

function cancelEventHandler(event) {
  showAction('Clicked:' + this.textContent);
  clickEventhandler.call(this, event);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.edit-link')
  .forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', clickEventhandler);
  });
document.querySelectorAll('.btn-cancel')
  .forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', cancelEventHandler);
  });
document.querySelectorAll(".save-details")
  .forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', saveEventHandler);
  });
```

```css
.edit-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  color: white;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.info {
  padding: 4em;
  background: lightcoral;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.details {
  padding: 4em;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#showMe {
  border solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container--lg">
  <a data-checkout="personal" class="edit-link">Edit Personal Details</a>
  <a data-checkout="payment" class="edit-link">Edit Payment Details</a>
  <div id="checkout-personal" class="contact-info info ">this is the Personal Details content</div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-personal" class="contact-info details hide">
    this is the Personal Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="personal">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn save-details" data-checkout="personal">Save</a>
  </div>
  <div id="checkout-payment" class="payment-info info">this is the Payment Details content</div>
  <div id="edit-checkout-payment" class="payment-info details hide">this is the Payment Details content in <b>Edit mode</b>
    <a class="btn btn-cancel" data-checkout="payment">cancel</a>
    <a class="btn save-details" data-checkout="payment">Save</a></div>
</div>
<div id="showme"></div>
```